# C# how to filter a list by different properties at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

Im pretty new to C#/Unity so forgive me.

Im writing a filtering system which will filter a list by any of the properties of the class at runtime.
Im planning on that building up some kind of whereclause to filter the lists (i know i could hit the server to get the list i need, but currently want to just filter the data i already have)

Say i have a list of class "MyClass" with 4 properties: "param1".."param4"

If i wanted to filter it normally by param1 and param2 i could do:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>(existinglist);
myList = myList.Where(g => g.param1 == somevalue && g.param2 == someothervalue).ToList();
```

How could i generate the same where clause at runtime?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean?  That is a run time.

Comment: i mean without having to code the properties i want to search like in my example, i need to build up a dynamic whereclause based on what the user wants to filter on

Comment: I don't see how letting the user choose a filter prevents you from that? What is the problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper method which dynamically builds and compiles lambda based on the passed list of filters. I've used `KeyValuePair<string, object>` to represent the filter information (`Key` for the property name, `Value` - well, for the property value), but of course you can adjust it for another data structure (like custom class etc.)

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> filters)
    {
        if (filters == null || !filters.Any()) return source;
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var body = filters
            .Select(filter => Expression.Equal(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, filter.Key),
                Expression.Constant(filter.Value)))
            .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate.Compile());
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var filters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("param1", somevalue),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("param2", someothervalue),
};
var myList = existinglist.Where(filters).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `Expression.PropertyOrField` inside the `Expression.Equal` be the `filter.Value` instead of the key ? You are comparing the constant with the value of the filter , or am i missing something ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian `string filter.Key` is the desired property/field **name**, while `object filter.Value` is the value.  And we are building expression `param.Name == value`.

Comment: Will this work as a  "like"  query or only an exact match?

Comment: @Peck_conyon You can think of `Equal` as a method taking 2 arguments and returning bool. Hence it could be replaced with any other 2 argument bool returning expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propName, object value)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    var propInfo = type.GetProperty(propName,BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter( type, "x" ); //x
    var memberAccessExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( parameterExpr, propInfo ); //x.Prop

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda( Expression.Equal(memberAccessExpr, Expression.Constant(value)), 
                                    parameterExpr );         //x=>x.Prop==value

    var mi = typeof(Enumerable)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.Name == "Where")
                .First(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(type);

    return (IEnumerable<T>)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda.Compile() });
}
```

You can now use it as

```
var test = new[] { new { a = 1 }, new { a = 2 } }.Where("a", 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Eser that makes sense! if i wanted to search multiple properties at one go, ie param1='1' and params2='2' could i do this in one where clause?

Comment: @Neil it means 2 `where`s

Comment: wait what, how is this any better than just using LINQs Where? have you gained anything for the price of losing type safety? FWICT OP is dealing with a known class with a known set of properties?

Comment: @kai See the title `how to filter a list by different properties at **runtime**`

Comment: @Eser filtering is ALWAYS done at runtime, it is a method, it cannot execute at compile time.

Comment: @kai :)) suppose the code inputs a value(for ex propertyname) from the user and does a filtering using it. Either you'll write many `if`s or use a dynamic approch like this...

Comment: why would you need many ifs? why can't you just accept a `Func<TSource, bool>` predicate and use `IEnumerable<TSource>.Where()`? this seems like such an extremely obfuscated, error-prone and hacky way to solve what seems to be a really trivial problem, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something here ...?

Answer (score -1):

A lambda expression is just shorthand for a function. So you can replace that lambda with any function which takes a Myclass and returns a bool. Then write in that method the code to evaluate what you need to dynamically - perhaps using reflection if necessary.

myList = myList.Where(myFunction).ToList();